# Levene Test NaN as a Result in R

Tags: r, t-test

I need some help regarding my code. I am having to dataframes which consist of Data for two kind of Bondsportfolios. I now want to to a levene test on the bid ask spread of the two portfolios.

The portfolios are in two different excel sheets which I importet into my datasets.

I use this as my code:

```
leveneTest(Portfolio1$BA, Portfolio2$BA)
```

When running it I receive the following results

```
Levene's Test for Homogeneity of Variance (center = median)
       Df F value Pr(>F)
group 254     NaN    NaN
        6               
Warning message:
In leveneTest.default(Portfolio1$BA, Portfolio2$BA) :
  Portfolio2$BA coerced to factor.
```

I tried to figure out why I just receive a NaN as result. I have the same number of observations in it, as well as data for all the dates in the dataframe. I do not understand, why it gives me de NaN as a Value.

The type of the data is double, changing it to numeric does not help either. Can soemone help me?

Many Thanks in advance

For the Data the output out of

```
dput(Portfolio1$BA)
c(0.777535489536076, 0.777535489536076, 0.777535489536076, 0.802626957412557, 
0.769391189814138, 0.811846919361921, 0.727535489536074, 0.747907214986097, 
0.752458656519829, 0.720993707010097, 0.759556563734818, 0.703285526123227, 
0.752144007024733, 0.647343772866969, 0.63278208693107, 0.631721059563881, 
0.640033660178545, 0.642631347870627, 0.630184399238986, 0.615571491292258, 
0.673781647885263, 0.638584809015073, 0.746165666617883, 0.696114444607053, 
0.66173715791014, 0.622149860968827, 0.663786038343333, 0.666112981121031,
```

and

```
dput(Portfolio2$BA)
c(0.733367481340555, 0.733367481340555, 0.733367481340555, 0.747065710522465, 
0.705627103761161, 0.696385189521438, 0.670847358407725, 0.664993414312892, 
0.649809746816919, 0.651397629152642, 0.69964876335431, 0.681999121908384, 
0.701551295185128, 0.61059563881165, 0.604156300307333, 0.62084004097761, 
0.719208254061174, 0.703987999414605, 0.618608224791454, 0.620474169471678, 
0.600834187033514, 0.609966339821456, 0.697373042587442, 0.700885409044341,
```

both Portfolios are a Dataframe consisting of 522 Observations and 6 variables. If i try the same with just two single Bonds (same structure in excel and also a data frame) it works completely finde.